# What does this line mean: lib=$1; shift

Tags: shell, unix

I am looking at a shell script. What does these two lines do?

```
lib=$1
shift
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are generally expected to have expended some of your own effort in attempting to track down a solution before asking for help on this site.

Comment: The two lines given are equivalent to `lib=$1; shift`, not `lib=$1 shift` -- the semicolon makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shift` traverses a shell's argument list. See the [man page](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?shift%201) for `shift`.

So after these two lines, `lib=$2`.

A clearer example:

```
echo “arg1= $1  arg2=$2”
shift
echo “arg1= $1  arg2=$2”
shift   
echo “arg1= $1  arg2=$2”
shift
```

Outputs:

```
arg1= 1 arg2=2
arg1= 2 arg2= 
arg1=   arg2=
```

---

Example 2:

```
echo “arg1= $1  arg2=$2 arg3=$3 arg4=$4”
shift
echo “arg1= $1  arg2=$2 arg3=$3 arg4=$4”
shift   
echo “arg1= $1  arg2=$2 arg3=$3 arg4=$4”
shift  
echo “arg1= $1  arg2=$2 arg3=$3 arg4=$4”
shift
echo “arg1= $1  arg2=$2 arg3=$3 arg4=$4”
shift
```

Output:

```
arg1=1 arg2=2  arg3=3 arg4=4
arg1=2 arg2=3  arg3=4 arg4=
arg1=3 arg2=4  arg3=  arg4=
arg1=4 arg2=   arg3=  arg4=
arg1=  arg2=   arg3=  arg4=
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I created a file called shell.sh and copied your command line into the file. Then I tested two command:
`sh shell.sh 1 2`, which showed me your outputs. I would suggest do another test with command: `sh shell.sh 1 2 3 4`. It explains what shift does very well.

Comment: Updated with a second example. If it was beneficial, consider marking as answer to help others with the same question.

Comment: "Traverses"? "Pops the first item off of" might be more accurate. There's not necessarily any traversal done -- if `$@` is stored as a linked list, for instance, a `shift` can be performed by changing only the head pointer for that list, with no traversal needed.

Comment: I couldn't think of the right term to use, so I used the term given in the man page description.